# clearInterval() on a specific setTimeout in an object array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, settimeout, clearinterval

I've created an object array of setTimeouts with unique ids. The idea is that I'd like to be able to clearInterval one of those setTimeouts using the id but I've been unable to figure out how.

Here's how I build the object array:

```
var loading = {};

loading[id] = setTimeout(function() {
    // function
}
```

And here's how I tried to clear the setTimeout:

```
clearInterval(loading[id]);
```

I thought would work but no such luck. It looks like this will work:

```
$.each(loading, function(index, value) {
    if (index == id) {
        clearInterval(loading[index]);
    }
}
```

but the idea of having to iterate through the entire array each time seems like a waste. Is there a one line solution for this?

Comment: I dont know why this `clearInterval(loading[id]);` would not work. Did you check what is inside `loading[id]` before clearing the interval?

Comment: I can't explain it but I removed the .each and if statement from around the clearInterval, changed index to id and now it works. I guess there was a typo in there somewhere. Thanks for confirming that it should work :)

Comment: "*Is there a one line solution for this?*" No. [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout) and [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) only accept a single ID. They would have to loop anyways if they did accept multiple. Though, you could define `clearTimeouts()` (plural) so the looping is at least contained. (And, as others have noted, you need to make sure you match up interval or timeout functions.)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong function to clear a timeout. If you are using timeouts you should use the "clearTimeout" function. Intervals are cleared by using "clearInterval" function.

```
var intervals = {};

intervals[0] = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('first');
}, 1000);

intervals[1] = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('second');
}, 1000);

$('#clearIntervalBtn').bind('click', function(i) {
    clearInterval(intervals[1]);
});
```

Here's an example on clearing intervals: http://jsfiddle.net/AG9Fh/15/